# Behringer guitar link and ASIO stuff

Tags: bass-guitar

I've been searching the web like crazy for some help. None has been found to date.

I've acquired a guitar link from Behringer, model UCG 102. It turns out that I can get my bass to be played on Guitar Rig, but I can't use any other software that uses sounds at the same time, as ASIO takes control of my in-board soundcard.

I've tried ASIO multi server and while I guess it would allow me to use Guitar Rig at the same time as other sound software, it does not help me with foobar (just a generic music player).

My intention here was to play my bass on Guitar Rig, along with some songs played with the music player. It turns out that the player doesn't use ASIO, so the multi server doesn't really help me here.

So, here it goes: how the heck can I play bass on the PC while listen to music on the same PC, using the Behringer guitar link? Do I need a dedicated sound card? Or am I just screwed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try [Audacity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/) for playback, as that is also capable of using ASIO.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the usb interface as your default playback device in windows. This should route everything to your headphone jack of the 102.

I would suggest using a DAW software and placing that song in a track, then using your guitar rig as a VST plugin. Since you are cost conscious, I'd recommend REAPER or Audacity. That way you can record yourself and listen back along with the track (assuming low latency).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the ASIO4All driver, which is sort of a wrapper for the onboard sound. A quick search for "UCG 102 asio" brings up people complaining about there only being the ASIO4ALL driver on the Behringer support page and not finding the Behringer-specific driver and that it may be buried somewhere in their support pages.

(see for example page 2: http://forum.music-group.com/showthread.php?7367-Where-did-the-Behringer-ASIO-drivers-for-the-UCG102-and-UM2-go/page2&s=01598cc1b63b2489cdab0eadb45aa6d3 )

To get your stuff working as you describe, you need a secondary speaker system (or a mixer to mix the PC and Behringer outputs etc).

For Guitar Rig, you would set input *and* output to the Behriger ASIO driver (not ASIO4ALL), and then connect the headphone-out on the behringer device to a mixer/amp/powered speaker system.

The PC audio will then no longer be in exclusive mode and you can use youtube, play mp3s using any software etc.

I personally use an old AV receiver and a subwoofer with satellite speakers connected to a {similar USB audio device} and a set of 2.1 PC speakers connected to the PC output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with the UGC 102, you could try to use both your internal sound card for your music and your UGC 102 for your bass, and mix both signals using a basic analog mixer.

Otherwise, you could buy a bigger audio interface with which you would have less limitations. In my personal case, I use an Edirol UA-101 with which I can do almost everything.

Comment: But how much would it cost? I've looked at such interfaces and they're not exactly cheap... I just need a solution to run an music player at the same time I play on the guitar rig. Is that impossible?